# Social rating from grid view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax-control-tookit

I want to provide rating of items of a SharePoint 2010 list from a grid view that is showing all the list items in a grid with branding.
Is there any way to add a rating column in a grid with Social Rating Control (yellow , blue & empty stars)??

Please suggest me any workaround about this issue..
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/01/custom-gridview-field-for-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 1):

1 way in can think of is using a GridView's [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event. In your grid, include an empty column, with say a Panel in it. Give the panel an ID.

Then using something like this, find the panel in the grid, and using the value of the rating field of the current item being bound, add images:

```
void YourGrid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    SPListItem item = (SPListItem)e.Row.DataItem;
    Panel stars = e.Row.Cells[?].FindControl("StarsPanel") as Panel;
    if(stars != null)
    {
      int rating = 0;
      int.TryParse(item["Rating"].Tostring(), out rating);
      for(int i = 0; i < rating)
      {
        //add images
      {
    }
  }
}
```